# switching tabs using javascript onclick

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="bubble">
        <div class="content recommend" style="display: block; ">
        <h1>Recommend to your friends</h1>

        <div id="bubble_tabs">    
            <ul style="font-size:11px;">
                <li id="tab1"><a class="" href="#" onclick="switch_bubble_tab(this,'#friends_inveni');return false;">Favor</a></li>
                <li id="tab2"><a href="#" onclick="switch_bubble_tab(this,'#friends_facebook');return false;" class="active">Facebook</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="friends_favor" class="friends_rec" style="display: none; ">
                <br>
                You currently have no friends. <a style="text-decoration:underline;" href="/Friends/Invite/">Invite friends</a> or send them a recommendation via Facebook or Email.
        </div>

        <div id="friends_facebook" class="friends_rec" style="display: block; ">
            <iframe src="" style="overflow:hidden;width:350px;height:400px;"></iframe>
        </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

I want to implement the switch_bubble_tab, so that when the tab is clicked it shows the div id passed to that function. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function switch_bubble_tab(obj) {
$(".friends_rec").hide(); 
$(".friends_rec").eq($(obj).parents("li").index()).show();
//HTML below: 
<li id="tab1"><a class="" href="#" onclick="switch_bubble_tab(this);">Favor</a></li>
```

Comment: it fades in and out, but the content is not reloaded

Comment: I beg your pardon. i goofed. i had it grabbing the index of the `a` that was clicked instead of it's parent `li` ...updating.

Comment: Yes. i just updated the answer to include `.parents("li")` which grabs the parent `li` and takes it's index

Comment: okay now it works, but if you test it out.. when it fades in and fades out. why is the hight suddenly huge?

Comment: Just saw it. Forgot about that - it's because the animations occur at the same time and thus the the first one is still there (fading out) as the second one fades in. There. Modified to quickly fade out the current and then fade in the new one. hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, i'm sorry. my last comment is wrong too... i am epic-failing today. Try slideToggle or toggle instead. updating the code. This time i've tested and it works. Sorry for the jumping around.

Comment: where should I put slideToggle at?

Comment: Just updated the code. You can put slideToggle in place of toggle in the updated answere there.

Comment: I see you updated your page, and realized another flaw in my code. I'm really sorry. I'm updating the code ONE MORE TIME. It really works this time. compltely. and totally. i tried it. Sorry about all this.